# Codeigniter subfolder named like controller

Tags: codeigniter, controllers

I'm trying to make folder in controller folder with exact name like controller in Codeigniter. Is it possible by some trick or something?

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJnbe.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it will be like

```
/controllers/manage/manage.php
```

you should add in /config/routes.php

```
$route['manage/(.*)'] = "manage/manage/$1";
$route['manage'] = "manage/manage";
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I incorrectly viewed the first time and thought manage.php was outside the manage folder.

It will work, but your URL will just have "manage" twice. You could change the routes config to remove the first "manage", but it will be less confusing and time-consuming to just name manage.php something different.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using the same name, but it is confusing. The best solution would be to change the name, but you can use just fine.

Remember to use the routes with 'manage/manage/function'.